# Uninstalling features karaf/servicemix

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-servicemix

I'm doing some tests, installing and uninstalling features and its behaviour.

I start with a clean servicemix 7.0.0.M1 install, it has cxf 3.1.4 and camel 2.16.2 by default.

If I type bundle:requirements 44 (camel-cxf in my case), all stuff related to cxf is resolved by version 3.1.4 (the only one installed right now).

Now I add cxf 3.1.9 repo and install it:

```
feature:repo-add cxf 3.1.9

feature:install cxf
```

After that, if I type bundle:requirements 44 it says all stuff related to cxf is resolved by version 3.1.9.

I try to uninstall cxf/3.1.9, after uninstall, when I type feature:list -i, it shows features related to cxf 3.1.9 as started, I assume its because camel-cxf 2.16.2 requirements are resolved by them.

A couple of questions:

1) Is there a way to know, given a feature, which bundles depend on it?

2) Is there a way to fully uninstall cxf even if there are bundles depending on it? I tried removing all directories in the data/cache folder and it seems to work (camel-cxf is resolved by cxf 3.1.4 again), I want to know if there is other way.

Answer (score 0):

The feature will be uninstalled completely if you also uninstall all features that depend on it. So try to also uninstall camel.

Comment: Yes, what I want to know if there is a way to know which are the features that depend on it, in this case I know it is camel, but it could happen that there are much more features and it doesn´t seem to be very practical to check for every bundle dependencies to see if they are resolved by the feature I want to remove.